# How to handle url+multiple otpional query params in node?

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express, query-string

I am making a rest api. And I have multiple optional params. Here is the solution i have taken, but is there another solution?
The url can be

```
www.myurl.com/
```

or

```
www.myurl.com/faqid/22
```

or

```
www.myurl.com/faqid/22/locale/english
```

Here is my implementation

```
var getFaq = (req, res) => {
    let faqDetails = FAQ.map(obj => obj);//it is a mock json for now
    faqDetails = req.params.faqid ? faqDetails.filter(obj => obj.id == req.params.faqid) : faqDetails;
    faqDetails = req.params.topic ? faqDetails.filter(obj => obj.topic == req.params.topic) : faqDetails;
    return res.status(200).send(faqDetails);
}
router.get('/:faqid/topic/:topic', getFaq)
router.get('/:faqid', getFaq)
router.get('/', getFaq)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you should try to organise your app routes in such a way that methods follow the Single Responsibility Principle where every function you write should do exactly one thing. It should have one clearly defined goal. In the above `getFaq` seems to be doing so many things.

You'd ideally want to divide them up to `getAll()`, `getSingle()` and `getTopic()` functions and then delegate each to the responsible route:

```
router.get('/:faqid/topic/:topic', getTopic)
router.get('/:faqid', getSingle)
router.get('/', getAll)
```

That way it's easier to unit-test and debug.